# Splunk: how to select not matching data across two sourcetype

Tags: outer-join, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I have following data in splunk in two different sourcetypes

**index="xyz" sourcetype="assets"**

```
name
--------
SERVER01
SERVER02
SERVER03
```

**index="xyz" sourcetype="computers"**

```
name
--------
SERVER02
SERVER03
SERVER05
```

i am trying to fetch data which is not matching in both sourcetypes

```
 name
 --------
 SERVER01
 SERVER05
```

i tried doing data selection using outer join as mentioned below but seems its not working

```
index="xyz" sourcetype="assets"
| table name
| join type=outer name
   [| search index="xyz" sourcetype="computers"
    | table name]
| table name
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stats command can do that.  Collect the servers from each sourcetype and count their number.  Those with a count of 1 don't match.

```
index=xyz (sourcetype=assets OR sourcetype=computers)
| stats count by name
| where count = 1
| table name
```